# Apache Ambari Installation suggestions in Linux RHEL5

Tags: hadoop

I need some suggestions for installing the Apache Ambari in existing 5-node Hadoop Cluster 1.2.1 version for monitoring purpose.

I am using RHEL5 version and in my cluster is mix of 64-bit & 32-bit machines.

I am now clueless to proceed for the installation.I have Horton works manuals for the installation.

I am looking for someone help and suggestions for the installation.

Thanks in advance!!!